# Does PHP automatically convert standard time to day light savings time?

Tags: php, date, datetime, time, timezone

Does PHP automatically convert standard time to day light savings time? For example we need time in `PST[$toTimezone]`timezone but PHP is returning PDT. Below is the example function we are using.

```
$fromTime = '2014-09-16 06:45:45';
$fromTimezone = 'GMT';
$toTimezone = 'PST';

function x($fromTime, $fromTimezone, $toTimezone,$format = 'l, F jS, Y g:i A T') {
  $fromTimezone = new \DateTimeZone($fromTimezone);
  $toTimezone = new \DateTimeZone($toTimezone);
  $orgTime = new \DateTime($fromTime, $fromTimezone);
  $toTime = new \DateTime($orgTime->format("c"));
  $toTime->setTimezone($toTimezone);
  return $toTime->format($format);
}
```

Regards,
Vamsi Krishna Grandhi

Comment: Actually PHP is looking at the server time.

Answer (score 3):

PHP will convert the time to the timezone currently observed. So, in the case of New York it would be in Eastern Daylight Time (-4) today and on the last day of the year, NY will be in Eastern Standard Time. Phoenix, Arizona which does not observe Daylight Savings Time is always in Mountain Standard Time.

```
$date = new DateTime('2014-09-16', new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
echo $date->format('c T');

$date = new DateTime('2014-09-16', new DateTimeZone('America/Phoenix'));
echo $date->format('c T');

$date = new DateTime('2014-12-31', new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
echo $date->format('c T');

$date = new DateTime('2014-12-31', new DateTimeZone('America/Phoenix'));
echo $date->format('c T');

2014-09-16T21:12:03-04:00 EDT
2014-09-16T18:12:03-07:00 MST
2014-12-31T00:00:00-05:00 EST
2014-12-31T00:00:00-07:00 MST
```